# TFlite Model Maker returns "Trying to decode BMP format using a wrong op" for a bunch of jpg images

Tags: tensorflow, classification, tensorflow-lite, image-classification

I'm working off this basic tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification on image classification using Tensorflow lite. However, the `image_classifier.create()` returns the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Trying to decode BMP format using a wrong op. Use `decode_bmp` or `decode_image` instead. Op used: DecodePng
 [[{{node cond/DecodePng}}]]
 [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_11083]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

I'm training the model using data from http://web.mit.edu/torralba/www/indoor.html. I've verified that there are no bitmap images in the dataset.

I'm on Python version 3.9.7 and tflite-model-maker version 0.3.4.

How might I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe path or header format, I had download and trying you may specific new header of the file < BM6f > OR < JFIF >

```
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Trying to decode BMP format using a wrong op. Use `decode_bmp` or `decode_image` instead. Op used: DecodePng
         [[{{node cond/DecodePng}}]]
         [[IteratorGetNext]]
         [[IteratorGetNext/_4]]
  (1) INVALID_ARGUMENT:  Trying to decode BMP format using a wrong op. Use `decode_bmp` or `decode_image` instead. Op used: DecodePng
         [[{{node cond/DecodePng}}]]
         [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_11154]
```

[Sample - errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULLlR.jpg)

[Sample - no errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6sJf.png)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried what you suggested but the error still persists. Same as before, it reaches around 70/439 on the first epoch and stops.

Comment: Does all pictures you using as dataset is normalized with same dimentsion ?

Comment: It is only Tensorflow create models and perform import dataset you may read it from : https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification